# What is the difference between the `num` and `count` parameters in a Caffe blob when using a Python layer?

Tags: python, caffe

In the [Euclidean Loss Example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py) for a Python layer in Caffe, there is usage of `bottom[0].num` as well as `bottom[0].count`.

It appears that both have exactly the same meaning.

From the Caffe [blob.hpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/blob.hpp), there are functions with the same name defined as:

```
inline int count() const { return count_; }
```

and

```
inline int num() const { return LegacyShape(0); }
```

It seems that `count_` keeps track of the number of elements in the blob, and this also seems to be the value returned by `num()`.

Is this the case? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [these Caffe docs](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Blob.html#a80ed3eddf98ffd408e9a627b1a7c2a9e), `num` is a "Deprecated legacy shape accessor num: use shape(0) instead."

On the other hand, [`count`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1Blob.html#a8674686a97c961b309b4420ead6626b5) is the product of all the dimensions.

So, `num` gives you a number of elements, each of which may have several channels, height, and width. `count` is the total count of values. They should only agree if every dimension in `shape` is 1, except for `shape(0)`.

Comment: I think num simply returns the value of the first dim, i.e., shape(0), instead of "a list of elements". For example, if the shape is [2, 3, 4, 5], then num() returns 2 and count() returns 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120.

Answer (score 0):

@Kundor has already given a good answer. I'll put a code snippet and it's output here for laters who still has a puzzle. And as you can see, the `count()` method is more like giving a stride, and `num()` together with `height()` `width()` displays dimensions.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <caffe/blob.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace caffe;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Blob<float> blob;
    cout << "size: " << blob.shape_string() << endl;

    blob.Reshape(1, 2, 3, 4);

    cout << "size: " << blob.shape_string() << endl;

    auto shape_vec = blob.shape();
    cout << "shape dimension: " << shape_vec.size() << endl;
    cout << "shape[0] " << shape_vec[0] << endl;
    cout << "shape[1] " << shape_vec[1] << endl;
    cout << "shape[2] " << shape_vec[2] << endl;
    cout << "shape[3] " << shape_vec[3] << endl;

    cout << "shape(0) " << blob.shape(0) << endl;
    cout << "shape(1) " << blob.shape(1) << endl;
    cout << "shape(2) " << blob.shape(2) << endl;
    cout << "shape(3) " << blob.shape(3) << endl;
    // cout << "shape(4) " << blob.shape(4) << endl;

    cout << "cout() test \n";
    cout << "num_axes() " << blob.num_axes() << endl; // 4
    cout << "cout() " << blob.count() << endl; // 24
    cout << "cout(0) " << blob.count(0) << endl; // 24
    cout << "cout(1) " << blob.count(1) << endl; // 24
    cout << "cout(2) " << blob.count(2) << endl; // 12
    cout << "cout(3) " << blob.count(3) << endl; // 4
    cout << "cout(4) " << blob.count(4) << endl;
    // cout << "cout(5) " << blob.count(5) << endl; // start_axis <= end_axis(5 vs. 4)

    // legacy interface
    cout << "num() " << blob.num() << endl;
    cout << "channels() " << blob.channels() << endl;
    cout << "height() " << blob.height() << endl;
    cout << "width() " << blob.width() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
size: (0)
size: 1 2 3 4 (24)
shape dimension: 4
shape[0] 1
shape[1] 2
shape[2] 3
shape[3] 4
shape(0) 1
shape(1) 2
shape(2) 3
shape(3) 4
cout() test
num_axes() 4
cout() 24
cout(0) 24
cout(1) 24
cout(2) 12
cout(3) 4
cout(4) 1
num() 1
channels() 2
height() 3
width() 4
```